# Hissing Sound when Turning Sharp

Tags: noise, jeep, steering

I drive a 1980 Jeep CJ-7, and I've noticed when I turn the wheel sharply to the left or right, I can hear a hissing sound. It seems to be coming from the engine compartment/end of the steering column area. Is this a potential problem, or nothing to worry about?

Thanks,

Marca

Comment: Probably something steering related... does it have power steering? When did this start? Side note: your Jeep is 33 years old, if the only thing wrong with it is a hissing sound, you deserve a pat on the back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the steering wheel is at the **end** of its travel (completely left/right) it is normal that the power steering pump starts making some extra noise

At **max travel**, the steering pump will produce its **maximum pressure** and will have to work the hardest. This *will* create a "hissing" type noise.

When the fluid level is **low**, then you will hear the pump moaning the whole travel range. You could easily check the fluid level yourself, there is a small dipstick fixed on the bottom side of the fluid fill cap. *(the cap itself has a yellow decal with a steering wheel on it)*

The pump itself is just at the right side of the alternator when standing in front of the engine *(It's been a while since I've seen one of those in the shop, so the location may be different)*.

Answer (score 0):

As cinelli stated this is definitely something related to the power steering pump. Check your power steering fluid level and maybe replace it.

If that doesn't help you may need a new power steering pump.